# What are some ways in Magento 2 that an order can fail to be cancelled?

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm testing an automated cron process that sends an email if an order fails to cancel, and am trying to find ways to trigger a cancellation failure in Magento 2. I'm aware an order can't be cancelled if its status is "Processing", but are there any other conditions where an order would fail to cancel? This is with Magento 2.4.3.